# Unable to access a dictionary key by using a loop, I'm getting a TypeError

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I made it short for the sake of an example.

```
import json    

info = '''
{
    "people":
    {
        "rick":
        {
            "age": 24
        }
    }
}
'''

data = json.loads(info)
```

The following code outputs: **rick** (which is what I expected)

```
for person in data["people"]:
    print(person)
```

In the following code I was expecting the output: **24**

```
for person in data["people"]:
    print(person["age"])
```

But instead I get: **TypeError: string indices must be integers**

By my understanding this means **rick** was converted to a **string**, no longer a dictionary, if that's the case, what's the correct way to output the **24**?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the `values` of your inner dictionary. The `data["people"]` is a dictionary in itself.

```
for person in data["people"].values():  
    print(person["age"])

# 24
```

Comment: It doesn't let me upvote for some reason, but thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mind another question? if the dictionary "people" had two keys instead of one (rick, ben), how would you access only the keys inside "rick" and not both?

Comment: @Jsh0s: You can then use `for person, age in data["people"].items():`  `if person == 'rick':` `print (age)`

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a dictionary iterates over its *keys* by default, so `person` is a string, the name of the key. You could change your second for loop to:

```
for person in data['people'].values():
    print(person['age'])
```

`dict.values()` yields the contained values, here dictionaries. Also, you could be interested by `dict.items()` :

```
for name, person in data['people'].items():
    print(name, person['age'])
# rick, 24
```

The first element is the key (the name) and the second the associated value (the dictionary).

Answer (score 1):

or you can use key,value pair:

```
for person,value in info["people"].items():
    print(value["age"])
```